# Итераторы для собственноручно написанных контейнеров

Tags: c++, vector, списки

Доброго времени суток. Проблема такая..Есть свой вектор и лист. 
Для векторы метод end возвращает значение так:

```
iter end() { return this->_array + this->count; }
```

iter - это псевдоним итератора

Для листа так:

```
iter end() { return this->tail; }
```

То бишь, этот элемент существует, он не "мифический". При переборе просто перегрузил несколько операторов сравнения. А вот для обобщённого алгоритма reverse это не работает. Как выглядит алгоритм:

```
template<typename IteratorIn>
void reverse(IteratorIn start, IteratorIn finish)
{
    while (start != finish)
    {
        swap(*start, *finish);
        ++start;  --finish;
    }
}

// swap
template<class Value>
void swap(Value &i1, Value& i2)
{
    Value tmp = i1;
    i1 = i2;
    i2 = tmp;
}
```

Так вот, как реализовать operator-- для итератора листа? 
Или как правильно получить итератор конца списка? 
Ибо для листа все работает нормально, а для вектора нет. Т.к. элемент не существующий, и в алгоритме reverse сначала надо сделать --finish, чтобы получить конец вектора. 
Надеюсь, я понятно всё обрисовал:) Спасибо заранее.

Comment: для обычного списка -- никак не сделать. Для этого нужен двунаправленный список.

Comment: список, разумеется, двунаправленный. Забыл указать.

Comment: Вообще-то так `reverse` не годится - `finish` должен указывать ЗА конец списка, и разыменовывать `end()` нельзя. А сделать такой итератор - ну пусть, грубо говоря, `end()` дает `nullptr`, а при применении `--` - в случае нулевого переносить его на последний элемент...

Comment: Так, с тем, что он должен указывать за конец списка - это понятно.. Но,  он будет указывать на nullptr? Как тогда вернуться к последнему элементу списка? Помогите пожалуйста с реализацией.
И про разыменовывание: в каком именно месте нельзя? Не очень понятно.. спасибо!

Comment: А что будет делать ваш `reverse` для _чётного_ количества элементов списка?

Comment: Да, я поймал эту ошибку, алгоритм уже переписан, всё функционирует надлежащим образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так вот, как реализовать operator-- для итератора листа?

для вашего случая, например, так

```
IteratorIn& operator--() 
{
    assert(ptr != nullptr && "list iterator not decrementable!");
    ptr = ptr->_prev;
    return *this;
}
```

где, `ptr` это уже реальный указатель на элемент списка - `ListNode* ptr` 
в котором есть указатели на следующий и предыдущий.

> И про разыменовывание: в каком именно месте нельзя? Не очень понятно..

`end()` должен указывать на элемент стоящий после хвостового, который есть `nullptr` поэтому его и нельзя разыменовывать, так как это неопределённое поведение в случае с обычным указателем, а итератор должен кидать исключение в этом случае

Вам нужно понять и переварить тот факт, что итератор это всего лишь удобная абстракцияя обычного указателя

> как правильно получить итератор конца списка?

так, например

```
iter end() const
{
    if (this->tail)
        return iter(tail->_next);
    return iter();
}
```

конечно, тут предпологается, что есть соответсвующие конструкторы для `iter`, которых желательно создать если их нет

и напоследок

список эффективнее переворачивать манипулируя указателями а не меняя местами сами элементы - так как в общем случае элементы списка, например, вполне могут быть какие нибудь массивы с большим кол-ов элементов, операции копирующего присвоения для которых будут тормозить весь процесс переворота вашего списка